# Does APACHE Drill supports AWS Kinesis streams

Tags: apache-drill

I have Kinesis Steams and want to query them using APACHE Drill. Does drill supports Kinesis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drill doesn't support AWS Kinesis. Please see Drill documentation:
https://drill.apache.org/docs/connect-a-data-source-introduction/

If you use Java app, consider Apache Camel use with [Drill](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-drill/src/main/docs/drill-component.adoc) and [AWS Kinesis](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-aws/src/main/docs/aws-kinesis-component.adoc) components.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using python.

Comment: If you still consider using Drill with python you might be interested in:
https://github.com/PythonicNinja/pydrill